# How to implement ComponentDidCatch in SPFx

Tags: reactjs, spfx

Could someone please show me how to implement ComponentDidCatch in SPFx. I did it successfully in ReactJs like this: 
Throwing an Error :

```
throw new Error('I crashed!');
```

and it would get caught here:

```
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
      // Catch errors in any components below and re-render with error message
      this.setState({
        error: error,
        errorInfo: errorInfo
      })
      // You can also log error messages to an error reporting service here
    }
```

However, when I tried to do the same for **SPFx** , I would get the below error in the browser console, while throwing the error:

***Uncaught (in promise) Error: I crashed***

Is there a way to catch this error in SPFx?

Comment: In the render() method, did you return any HTML, if the Errorinfo is present?